# Smalltalk ReferenceStream has problems with new instance variables?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

In Pharo Smalltalk I'm using ReferenceStream to serialise a list of objects -- here's the class definition of the objects I'm serialising:

```
Object subclass: #Task
instanceVariableNames: 'title notes list project dateNextAction dateCreated dateCompleted importance selected'
classVariableNames: 'Database'
poolDictionaries: ''
category: 'ToDo'
```

I'm using the `SMFileDatabase` method described here:
http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/persistency/image-based-persistency

This has been working well, and it's been nice not to have to use a database for my prototype app.

Howevere, here's the problem: when I add a new instance variable `person` to `Task` the load from ReferenceStream breaks:

```
Object subclass: #Task
instanceVariableNames: 'title notes list project person dateNextAction dateCreated dateCompleted importance selected'
classVariableNames: 'Database'
poolDictionaries: ''
category: 'ToDo'
```

It seems to not spot the new variable, and load the values into the wrong slots, so person takes the value of `dateNextAction`, `dateNextAction` takes `dateCreated` and so on.

How can I stop this happening?

I've got it working by placing the new variable at the end of the list, but I'd like to group variables by type.

Answer (score 6):

ReferenceStream is not supported anymore and has been deleted in Pharo 2.0. You should use Fuel which is well written, well documented, well tested and very fast. http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/web/pier/software/Fuel

Comment: ...and you can install it in Pharo 1.4 too. So is a win-win :)

Comment: and just read the code for ReferenceStream to know why you want to use Fuel :)

Answer (score 6):

`SmartRefStream` should help you. To quote from the documentation:

> Ordinary ReferenceStreams assume that the names and order of instance variables is exactly the same when an object file is written and read.
>   SmartRefStream allows object files to be read even after instance variables have changed or the entire class has been renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Those wanting to finish the example in the book, follow these steps:

**1. Go back in time** and get a Pharo 1.4 from: https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/?group_id=1299

Scroll down and look for One-Click Pharo 1.4 and get the latest build, if there is a newer one than: https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/file/31359/Pharo-1.4-14457-OneClick.zip

Use the Configuration Browser to install Seaside and you're done.

1a. Or use the legacy development prebuilt Seaside, Scriptaculous, Magritte, Pier image running on Pharo 1.3 here: http://www.seaside.st/distributions/Seaside-3.0.7-final.zip

I got lucky using a Pharo VM from here: http://files.pharo.org/vm/pharo/20/mac/stable.zip

**2. Get your code out** of the current image via Monticello and then "back" into the older image. Success!

**PS.** More details here:
[FileDirectory and ReferenceStream Class equivalents in Pharo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285936/filedirectory-and-referencestream-class-equivalents-in-pharo)