# FileDirectory and ReferenceStream Class equivalents in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I'm doing the persistance example at:

http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/persistency/image-based-persistency

It involves creating a method that uses the FileDirectory class like this:

```
SMFileDatabase class>>backupDirectory
    ^ (FileDirectory default directoryNamed: self name) assureExistence.
```

Pharo seems to be unable to find the Class and the closest that comes out in search is FileDirectoryWrapper. Will this do?

NB. I can't figure this out myself since I've never used FileDirectory or FileDirectoryWrapper before so I'm in the dark.

**Later edit:**

Found another one ReferenceStream. They both seem to have been deprecated.
Mentioned here:
http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/pharo-project/2012-June/065765.html

Because they apparently had problems, mentioned here:
[Smalltalk ReferenceStream has problems with new instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740734/smalltalk-referencestream-has-problems-with-new-instance-variables)

**Later edit 2:**

It seems the answers below will work for FileDirectory, and ReferenceStream can be replaced by Fuel in newer Pharo releases.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15742159/293856

SmartRefStrem seems another solution to the bugs. All this is untested by me.
[Smalltalk ReferenceStream has problems with new instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740734/smalltalk-referencestream-has-problems-with-new-instance-variables)

**However:**

Those wanting to finish the example in the book need to go back in time and get a Pharo 1.4 from:
https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/?group_id=1299

Scroll down and look for One-Click Pharo **1.4** and get the latest build, if there is a newer one than:
https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/file/31359/Pharo-1.4-14457-OneClick.zip

or **1.3**.

I got lucky with a Pharo VM from here:
http://files.pharo.org/vm/pharo/20/mac/stable.zip

With a prebuilt Seaside image running on Pharo 1.3 here:
http://www.seaside.st/distributions/Seaside-3.0.7-final.zip

Get your code out of the current image via Monticello and then "back" into the older image. Success!

Comment: A Note: Since Monticello initially used `DataStream`/`SmartRefStream`, and Pharo supports Monticello/MCZs, there has to be a compatibility thing. And indeed, `MCDataStream` seems to provide at least a subset of `SmartRefStream`'s  functionality

Comment: I'll get back to you on this after I test it out in the example. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is like this:

```
self name asFileReference ensureCreateDirectory.
```

Comment: Very simple indeed. Edited the question to include whole story. I'll test your answer when I start hacking and getting it to work on newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

Pharo switched to `FileSystem` some time after the book was published.

The equivalent for the first code is now

```
SMFileDatabase class>>backupDirectory
    ^(FileSystem disk workingDirectory / self name) ensureCreateDirectory
```

(also, regarding `ReferenceStream`, the answer given by Damien in the post you referenced still holds true)

Comment: You mean using Fuel instead of ReferenceStream. I thought so too but I'd rather finish this as it is and then start hacking. Managed to get it working by getting my code out via Monticello then going back in time, to a Pharo  VM 2.0 to run a prebuilt Seaside 3.0.7 image in Pharo 1.3. Now the code from the book works without any modifications.